# How to setup varying coding keys for enums in swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, struct, codable

I am trying to store some values into firebase firestore database using Codable. I have a requirement to use varying coding keys for the struct. My struct example is as follows:

```
struct MyStruct: Codable {
    let userID: String
    let userName: String
    let useCase: String

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case userID = "id"
    case userName = "name"
    case useCase = "use_case_\(Int.random(in: 0..<100))" // I want this key to append random number with it.
 }
}
```

The CodingKey protocol does not allow to add this varying key values in swift. Can anyone help me to sort this issue? Are we able to customize CodingKeys to achieve a solution?

Comment: You can apply a custom `KeyDecodingStrategy` but this depends on more details what you are going to accomplish.

Comment: @vadian These values are used only to be stored in firestore. My requirement does have a situation in which same user can perform useCase multiple times. As of now if i use some string for ex: useCase = "use_case" it will be overwritten in firestore. I need to have different useCase keys like "use_case_14", "use_case_87" etc to avoid the overwriting problem. Thanks

Comment: Isn't the solution then to add a new property that holds this unique (?) number instead of having a key with a dynamic name

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Do you mean to add a property in the struct which should be assigned to the enum case ? if yes, i tried that and getting this error "Raw value for enum case must be a literal"

Comment: No I meant a normal property like the others , it should be added to the enum (if needed) as it own item

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Can you please provide code sample of what you are explaining?

Comment: I would use an simple array or if the key is important a dictionary. Like `struct MyStruct: Codable { useCases: [String: String] }`

Comment: Property: `let useCaseId: Int` And in enum, `case useCase = "use_case" case useCaseId = "use_case_id"`.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I need to have this id (Int) to be appended along with the "use_case_append_id_here" as its key. I think i should use a dictionary to have (key as dynamic with value).

Comment: @JohannesStarke Your solution is working for me. If i provide a dictionary as (key, value) to useCase, the key is getting stored in firestore. In this case i should avoid the CodingKey for useCase. Code should be like: struct MyStruct: Codable {
    let userID: String
    let userName: String
    let useCase: [String: String]

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case userID = "id"
    case userName = "name"
    case useCase
 }
}

Comment: Thankyou vadian, joakim danielson and johannes Starke for spending time and providing solutions to my problem.